# How can I apply Girvan Newman and Markov Cluster Algorithms in Gephi 0.9.1?

Tags: graph, markerclusterer, gephi

I am a beginner in Gephi, and i want to apply Girvan Newman and Markov Cluster Algorithms in Gephi 0.9.1 on my graph(Nodes-Edges)
I'm downloaded these plugins from gephi.org https://marketplace.gephi.org/plugin/girvan-newman-clustering/  but, when i'm trying to install them in Gephi ,this error is shown to me! 
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ELJO1.jpg)
i understand it, and i downloaded these missing plugins but with extensions .zip or .jar which don't accept in Gephi .. and as another attempt to resolve this error, I installed Gephi 0.8.2 beta and 0.7 also, then they correctly installed but, basically they don't start opening.

I wish you help me.
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The plugins have been made for Gephi 0.8.2, the developers made some major changes with version 0.9 and the plugins will need to be ported.
It might be worth contacting the author to see if they plan on porting it, or try doing it yourself.

The code is here 
https://github.com/jaroslav-kuchar/GirmanNewmanClustering and Gephi have made a tool to help port old plugins so it may be trivial, more info can be found here https://github.com/gephi/gephi-maven-plugin